# Placing multiple jquery sliders on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am having problems with multiple sliders on a page.

slider: http://landofcoder.com/jquery-plugins/lof-jslidernew-plugin.html

Currently I am including the sliders from external html with jquery:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadslide1() 
{ 
    $("#includeslider1").load("slider1.html");
} 
function loadslide2() 
{ 
    $("#includeslider2").load("slider2.html"); 
} 
</script> 


<style type="text/css">
body {width:900px; height: 600px; background-color: black;}
</style>

    </head>
    <body>

   <div id="includeslider1"></div>
   <script>loadslide1()</script> 
   <div id="includeslider2"></div>
   <script>loadslide2()</script>  

    </body>
```

slider1 code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<!-- Slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lofc-layout.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lofc-style2.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function(){ 
        var buttons = { previous:$('#jslidernews2 .button-previous') ,
                        next:$('#jslidernews2 .button-next') };          
        $('#jslidernews2').lofJSidernews( { interval:5000,
                                                easing:'easeInOutQuad',
                                                duration:1200,
                                                auto:true,
                                                mainWidth:684,
                                                mainHeight:300,
                                                navigatorHeight     : 100,
                                                navigatorWidth      : 310,
                                                maxItemDisplay:3,
                                                buttons:buttons } );                        
    });

</script>
<style>

    ul.lof-main-wapper li {
        position:relative;  
    }
</style>
<!-- Slider -->
</head>
<body>


<!------------------------------------- THE CONTENT ------------------------------------------------->
<div id="jslidernews2" class="lof-slidecontent" style="width:980px; height:300px;">
    <div class="preload"><div></div></div>


            <div  class="button-previous">Previous</div>

             <!-- MAIN CONTENT --> 
              <div class="main-slider-content" style="width:684px; height:300px;">
                <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                    <li>
                            <img src="images/thumbl_980x340.png" title="Newsflash 2" >           
                          <div class="slider-description">
                            <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 1" href="#Category-1">/ Newsflash 1 /</a> <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 1</h4>
                            <p>The one thing about a Web site, it always changes! Joomla! makes it easy to add Articles, content,...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div>
                    </li> 
                   <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_002.png" title="Newsflash 1" >           
                         <div class="slider-description">
                           <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 2" href="#Category-2">/ Newsflash 2 /</a>  <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 2</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! makes it easy to launch a Web site of any kind. Whether you want a brochure site or you are...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div>
                    </li> 
                   <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_003.png" title="Newsflash 3" >            
                        <div class="slider-description">
                          <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 3" href="#Category-3">/ Newsflash 3 /</a>   <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 3</h4>
                            <p>With a library of thousands of free Extensions, you can add what you need as your site grows. Don't...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div>
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_004.png" title="Newsflash 5" >            
                        <div class="slider-description">
                          <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 4" href="#Category-4">/ Newsflash 4 /</a>   <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 4</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div>
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_005.png" title="Newsflash 5" >            
                        <div class="slider-description">
                           <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">/ Newsflash 5 /</a>    <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                           <h4>Content of Newsflash 5</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div>
                    </li> 
                    <li>

                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_006.png" title="Newsflash 5" >            
                        <div class="slider-description">
                          <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 6" href="#">/ Newsflash 6 /</a> <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 6</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div>
                    </li> 

                  </ul>     
            </div>
           <!-- END MAIN CONTENT --> 
           <!-- NAVIGATOR -->
            <div class="navigator-content">
                  <div class="navigator-wrapper">
                        <ul class="navigator-wrap-inner">
                          <li>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/791902news3.jpg" />
                                    <h3> NewsFlash 1 </h3>
                                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu...
                                </div>    
                            </li>
                             <li>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/435576news10.jpg" />
                                    <h3> NewsFlash 2 </h3>
                                    <span>20.01.2010</span> -In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                                </div>    
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/641906img1.jpg" />
                                    <h3> NewsFlash 3 </h3>
                                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                                </div>     
                            </li>

                           <li>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/416719news7.jpg" />
                                    <h3> NewsFlash 4</h3>
                                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                                </div>
                            </li>    
                            <li>
                                 <div>
                                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/641906img1.jpg" />
                                    <h3> NewsFlash 5</h3>
                                    <span>20.01.2010</span> -In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                                 </div>   
                            </li>
                           <li>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/416719news7.jpg" />
                                    <h3> NewsFlash 6</h3>
                                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                                </div>
                            </li>           
                        </ul>
                  </div>

             </div> 
          <!----------------- END OF NAVIGATOR --------------------->
          <div class="button-next">Next</div>

         <!-- BUTTON PLAY-STOP -->
          <div class="button-control"><span></span></div>
          <!-- END OF BUTTON PLAY-STOP -->

<!------------------------------------- END OF THE CONTENT ------------------------------------------------->



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Slider 2 is the same except with id changed to make them unique.

Sorry for the large code dump but to see what is going on it is necessary.

Any help or suggestions greatly received...

(semi working example (not chrome for some reason))

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I cannot get both sliders to work...one breaks the other.  Or at least  the second one ends up with less functionality - it controls the first one

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as you do. I find it is no a good way to find a html element via it's ID. `$('.class').each(function(i,obj){ /* do sth */})` can handle the business.

Check [this post](http://gosteven.com/blog/2012/08/29/multiple-sliders-on-one-page-jquery/) and there is a sample in it.

Hope it will help.